# how to pass json data into query string and use that data in another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Here table contains book details which contains book name, author, pric, ISBN and category. When user click on Book Name it should pass the data to another page using querystring

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="book.js">
    <body ng-app="mymodule" >
    <div ng-controller="myController" >
          <table border=2>
            <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>ISBN</th>
              <th>NAME</th>
              <th>AUTHOR</th>
              <th>CATEGORY</th>
              <th>PRICE</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="book in books">
                <td>{{ book.ISBN }}</td>
                <td ><a href="" ng-click="getdetail(book)">{{ book.Name }}</a></td>
                <td>{{ book.Author }}</td>
                <td>{{ book.Category }}</td>
                <td>{{ book.price }}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

    books.js        
    var myapp = angular.module('mymodule', []);
     myapp.controller("myController", function($scope, $http,$window) {
      $http.get("https://api.myjson.com/bins/p4ujn").then(function(response) {
            $scope.books = response.data;
            $scope.getdetail=function(){
              $scope.getbookdetail=this.book;
              $window.location.href = "orderpage.html";     
            }
      }); 
    });
    orderpage.html
    <script type="text/javascript" src="book.js"></script>
    <body ng-app="mymodule" >
      <div ng-controller="myController" >
          {{getbookdetail.Name}}<br>
          {{getbookdetail.Author}}
          {{getbookdetail.price }}<br>
        </div>
    </body
```

Answer (score 0):

So you said this: 'When user click on Book Name it should pass the data to another page using querystring'

Querystring is not the best method to use for something like this. You're better off learning about [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) and setting up routes that handle this. You have your initial state, then you can create another state to display each book. Something like this:

```
.state('initial', {
  url: 'some/initial',
  template: 'some/initial/template.html',
  params: {
    name: null,
    price: null,
    author: null,
    isbn: null,
    category: null
  }
})
.state('read-book-details', {
  parent: 'initial',
  url: 'some/url',
  template: 'some/template.html',
  params: {
    name: null,
    price: null,
    author: null,
    isbn: null,
    category: null
  }
})
```

Then when you're transitioning from one 'state' to another, you do it like so passing along the parameters you want:

```
$state.go('read-book-details',
  { name: book.name, price: book.price, author: book.author });
```

On the 'other' page's controller (ie the controller for the 'read-book-details' state) you can inject $state and get the parameters that are passed in via $state.params (ie., $state.params.price)

A second option for you is to have a service that you can store the data in, then retrieve from anywhere else. This obviously becomes useful when you start to pass around larger amounts of data rather than simpler smaller pieces (like name, price).